# The best way to shorten this code?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a fiddle and seem to have a lot of JQuery for what seems to be a simple animation. Is there a way to shorten this at all as it seems a bit heavy?

Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9vr2j7LL/

JQuery -

```
// Services

// Mens
$("#mens").hover(function(){
    $("#mens .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
    $("#mens .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});

// Womens
$("#womens").hover(function(){
    $("#womens .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
    $("#womens .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});

// Kids
$("#kids").hover(function(){
    $("#kids .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
    $("#kids .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});

// Work Wear
$("#workwear").hover(function(){
    $("#workwear .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
    $("#workwear .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});

// Education
$("#education").hover(function(){
    $("#education .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
    $("#education .box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd wager you're getting downvotes because of the way you phrased the question in the post title. The "best" way is very opinion based. You might try to restructure how you're asking this to get a better response from the community. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question should be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#id1,#id2,...#idN').hover(function() {
     $('.box', this).stop().fadeToggle(500);
 },
 function() {
     $('.box', this).stop().fadeToggle(500);
 });
```

OR:

```
$('.box').parent().hover(function(){
    $('.box', this).stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

OR:

```
$('div:has(.box)').hover(function(){
    $('.box', this).stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/9vr2j7LL/6/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/9vr2j7LL/7/)

Comment: That's moot.  The best approach is to fix the HTML structure.

Comment: @alexfreiria wouldn't *"the best for the current structure"* be `$('body > div')`? :)

Comment: or `$('body').on('hover', 'div:has(.box)', function(){ /* ... */ });` ;P

Comment: @alexfreiria the latter causes the `.box` to fade only when the `.box` is touched, not its container.

Answer (score 3):

Give all those elements a common class (e.g. `hover`)

Then, use this code:

```
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    $('.box', this).stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

There's no need to use two callbacks if the `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` callbacks do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Simply give all your elements with this function a class name which links them together. For example:

```
<div id="mens" class="hover">
```

Then simply get the `.box` element contained within the element you're hovering over by calling `$(this).find('.box')`:

```
$(".hover").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.box').stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Note that there's no need to repeat the function in the hover if both do the same thing.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9vr2j7LL/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#mens,#womens,#kids,#workwear,#education").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
},
function(){
     $(this).children(".box").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

[Try here ;)](http://jsfiddle.net/9vr2j7LL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this can easily be accomplished using a CSS transition, no JavaScript necessary (and probably less overhead with this approach):

`transition: background 2s;`

http://jsfiddle.net/9hctsxme/

Comment: True, this will not work on prehistoric browsers. But worth mentioning and working on all newer browsers.

Comment: also worth noting that a background fade is not the same as a jQuery `fadeToggle`, which AFAICR will actually set the element to `display: none` causing a page reflow when it completes.